# Remove row/columns with any/all NaN values

Tags: python, r, pandas, filter, data.table

In python with pandas, I can do the following:

```
# Drop columns with ANY missing values
df2 = df.dropna(axis=1, how="any")

# Drop columns with ALL missing values
df2 = df.dropna(axis=1, how="all")

# Drop rows with ANY missing values
df2 = df.dropna(axis=0, how="any")

# Drop rows with ALL missing values
df2 = df.dropna(axis=0, how="all")
```

How do I similarly filter rows/columns in a R data.table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `|` or `&`

```
library(data.table)
#Drop rows with any missing values
setDT(df1)[df1[, !Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, is.na))]]
#Drop rows with all missing values 
setDT(df1)[df1[, !Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na))]]

#Drop columns with any and all missing values
Filter(function(x) !any(is.na(x)), df1)
Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), df1)
#or use
setDT(df1)[, unlist(df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) any(!is.na(x)))]), with = FALSE]
setDT(df1)[, unlist(df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) all(!is.na(x)))]), with = FALSE]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(c(NA, 0:5), 4*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
df1[3] <- NA
```